# if one item is clicked, remove the other items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm learning Javascript and jQuery and I'm stuck at this one problem. Let's say my code looks like this:

```
<div id="hey"> hey </div>
<div id="how"> how </div>
<div id="are"> are </div>
<div id="you"> you </div>
```

Now, if i click one of the div's, i want the other ones to disappear.
I know, I could create 4 functions for each one of them with `on.click hey` and `display none` with `how` , `are` and `you`. But is there a easier way? I bet there is, with `classes` maybe?

Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get reference to its "brothers".

> <sub>Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .siblings() method allows us to search through the siblings of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.</sub>

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hey"> hey </div>
<div id="how"> how </div>
<div id="are"> are </div>
<div id="you"> you </div>
```

Or you can hide all the other `div` which not the clicked element using [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

> <sub>Remove elements from the set of matched elements.</sub>

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $('div').not(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hey"> hey </div>
<div id="how"> how </div>
<div id="are"> are </div>
<div id="you"> you </div>
```

Comment: :) I offered you another way to do this. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can just hide `siblings()` of clicked div.

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().fadeOut()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hey">hey</div>
<div id="how">how</div>
<div id="are">are</div>
<div id="you">you</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Mosh Feu offered more though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not` to avoid element and `this` will indicate current instance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").on("click",function(){
    $("div").not(this).hide("slow");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hey"> hey </div>
<div id="how"> how </div>
<div id="are"> are </div>
<div id="you"> you </div>
```

Comment: downvoter  please add comment reason as my answer matching requirement of PO

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there are some easier ways and I could tell a one from it,

Set a common class to all the elements that you are gonna target,

```
<div class="clickable" id="hey"> hey </div>
<div class="clickable" id="how"> how </div>
<div class="clickable" id="are"> are </div>
<div class="clickable" id="you"> you </div>
```

And you have to bind a single click event by using a class selector,

```
$(".clickable").on("click", function(){ });
```

Now use the `.siblings()` functions to hide the required elements,

```
$(".clickable").on("click", function(){
   $(this).siblings(".clickable").hide();
});
```

But using a toggle instead of hide would sounds logical,

```
$(".clickable").on("click", function(){
   $(this).siblings(".clickable").toggle();
});
```

Since you can do the same operation over all the elements.

Comment: you can simply do `$('.clickable').not(this).hide()` inside a click's callback

Comment: @PanamaProphet What simplicity I am missing when using `.siblings()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to each of the elements:

```
<div id="hey" class='sth'> hey </div>
<div id="how" class='sth'> how </div>
<div id="are" class='sth'> are </div>
<div id="you"class='sth' > you </div>
```

And write a js function onclick.

1. Remove class 'sth' from 'this' element in this function
2. Hide all elements with class 'sth'  `$('.sth').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

For this example - you don't need to add any further selectors to target the div's although in reality - this solution wwould cause all divs on the page to be affectecd - adding classes would be my actual suggestion: - but this works for this example. Click a div and all divs are hidden then the clicked one is shown. I also added a reset button to allow all divs to reappear.

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  $('div').hide();
  $(this).show();
});

  $('#reset').click(function(){
     $('div').show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hey"> hey </div>
<div id="how"> how </div>
<div id="are"> are </div>
<div id="you"> you </div>
<hr/>
<button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").on("click",function(){
     $("div").not(this).toggle("slow");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hey"> hey </div>
<div id="how"> how </div>
<div id="are"> are </div>
<div id="you"> you </div>
```